# Dynamic bootstrap grid layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a dynamic grid layout using bootstrap and C#.

What I'm trying to achieve in HTML is something like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3"></div>
</div>
```

Basically, a repeater which wraps a  around the col-md-3 div's.

In my view I have:

```
@{
    int productsPerRow = 4;
    int products = 8;

    for (int i = 1; i <= products; i++)
    {
        bool startDiv = (i % (productsPerRow + 1) == 0);

        @Html.Raw(startDiv ? "<div class='row'>" : "");

        @Html.Raw("<div class="col-md-3"></div>");

        bool endDiv = (i % productsPerRow == 0) || (i != 1 && i == productsPerRow);
        @Html.Raw(endDiv ? "</div>" : "");
    }

}
```

From the code in my view what it's trying to do is create `<div class="row">` when it's reached the `productsPerRow + 1` by also doing an is divisible by the productsPerRow check.

And then, ofcourse close the div by appending `</div>` when we have reached the productsPerRow.

However, this isn't doing what's expected and instead is printing like:

```
  <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3"></div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
  <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3"></div>
</div>
```

What could I be doing wrong? And is there an easier way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrong because `1 % 5` is 1, but when `i` is 1 this is sthe first line and `<div>` should be. So, instead of `i % (productsPerRow + 1)` use `(i - 1) % productsPerRow`:

```
@{
    int productsPerRow = 4;
    int products = 8;

    for (int i = 1; i <= products; i++)
    {
        bool startDiv = ((i - 1) % productsPerRow  == 0);

        @Html.Raw(startDiv ? "<div class='row'>" : "");

        @Html.Raw("<div class="col-md-3"></div>");

        bool endDiv = (i % productsPerRow == 0) || (i != 1 && i == productsPerRow);
        @Html.Raw(endDiv ? "</div>" : "");
    }

}
```

But I think that with nested loop, it'll be more pretty:

```
@{
  const int productsPerRow = 4;
  int products = 8;
  const int rows = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)products / productsPerRow); // Because if one products need one more row, we should one more row, so I round up
}

@for (int i = 0, productNum = 0; i < rows; i++, productNum++)
{
  <div class="row">
    @for (int j = 0; j < productsPerRow && productNum < products; j++, productNum++)
    {
      <div class="col-md-3">@productsArr[productNum]</div>
      @* This is an example how to access the products if stored in an array via nested loop *@
    }
  </div>
}
```

#### Edit:

The previous version had a bug - if, for example, there is 9 products, then `rows` will assign to 3, the outer loop wil run 3 times, and in the third iteration, the nestede loop will run 4 times (`productsPerRow` times), even thought there is only one product remained. To fix that, I appended a variable named `productNum`, which stores the index of the current product (the code for calculating its value is a little complicated; you can debug it and see how this variable changes correctly). Then, in the nested loop, I also check that we didn't finish the products iterating (`productNum < products`).

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old question but I came across this myself today and found an error in Chayim Friedman's edit. I do not have the reputation to post a comment to that answer, but in case this helps someone else, I wanted to add it.

You can only iterate over productNum in the nested loop.  Adding to it in the outer loop will cause you to be one higher productNum than the actual model count so you will have one product (or whatever) missing.

It should be like so:

```
@{
  const int productsPerRow = 4;
  int products = 8;
  const int rows = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)products / productsPerRow); // Because if one products need one more row, we should one more row, so I round up
}

@for (int i = 0, productNum = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
  <div class="row">
    @for (int j = 0; j < productsPerRow && productNum < products; j++, productNum++)
    {
      <div class="col-md-3">@productsArr[productNum]</div>
      @* This is an example how to access the products if stored in an array via nested loop *@
    }
  </div>
}
```